# React Native Fetch Api - Handling Promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

```
fetch(loginURL, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            user_name: email,
            password: password,
          })
        })
        .then((response) => {console.log(response.json())})
        .then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

[This is my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKXiT.png)

I want to access the token and store it in my app but as you can see I'm getting undefined when trying to access the promise.

Comment: I posted an answer, let me know if it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```js
fetch(loginURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user_name: email,
        password: password,
      })
    })
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```